# How to accept key-value pairs in order from POM - Maven

Tags: java, maven, collections, maven-2, maven-3

I need to accept a set of key - value pairs from my POM and use them in my Mojo. I want to maintain the input order as given by the user. My POM looks as follows right now:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>text-replace-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
       ...
        <configuration>
           <replacements>
            <property>
              <name>ABCD</name>
              <value>XYZ</value>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>XYZ</name>
              <value>PQR</value>
            </property>
          </replacements>
         ...
       </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I am accepting the `replacements` inside my Mojo as Java.util's `Properties` which I think implements Maps and is hence not ordered.

I've tried using LinkedHashMap instead of Properties but mojo doesn't seeem to understand it.

I also tried taking in the parameters as follows, but doesn't work:

```
  @Parameter(property = "replacer.replacements", required = true)
  private List replacements;

  @Parameter(property = "replacer.replacements.property")
  private Map eachPair;
```

this gives me an error: Error loading class 'com.training.replacer.Property'

Could you suggest me a way to achieve an ordered key-value pairs input from POM.xml? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned using Java's Properties and converted my POM's outer `replacements`  parameter with a list variable in my mojo - `List<myClass>`. I achieved this by creating my own class for key,value pair and providing the source package name in  POM.xml. I just need to keep the names of my data members same as the POM's property names and Maven will populate the object's data members.

Refer - https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Objects